# Preserving Image quality

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have a winform C# desktop application.

I have a constant stream of jpegs coming in.
I am comparing the current image with the previous 1.
By using a 3rd party tool - Emgu - I can create a new image that contains just the differences.

I then convert that image to a memory stream and then to a byte array.

In the receiving application I take this byte array and load the image via a memory stream using these bytes.

The trouble is that the image degrades quite a lot.

If I save the image to the hard drive before converting it to a memory stream on the client side the quality of the image is good.

The problem lies when i load it as a memory stream.

I encode it as jpeg.
If I encode it as a PNG before sending to the server the quality is good again.
The trouble with encoding to PNG the size in the byte array shoots up.

What my intention was all along was to reduce the number of bytes I have to upload to improve response time.

Am I doing something wrong or can this not be done?

This is my code:

```
Bitmap imgContainingDifference
    = GetDiffFromEmgu(CurrentJpegImage, PreviousJpegImage);

using (System.IO.MemoryStream msIn = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
  holding.Save(msIn, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  data = msIn.ToArray();
}

//test here
using (System.IO.MemoryStream msOut = new System.IO.MemoryStream(_data))
{
   Bitmap testIMG = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(msOut);
}

//result is image is poor/degrades
```

If I do this instead:

```
using (System.IO.MemoryStream msIn = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
  holding.Save(msIn, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
  data = msIn.ToArray();
}

using (System.IO.MemoryStream msOut = new System.IO.MemoryStream(_data))
{
   Bitmap testIMG = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(msOut);
}

//Image is good BUT the size of the byte array is 
//10 times the size of the CurrentFrame right at the start.
```

This is what the image looks like when using the kid suggestion from :

[image]

I have now tried using a encoder from the kind suggestion from @MagnatLU and I also get the same quality of image if I use FreeImage.Net.

Comment: You're asking to have your cake and eat it too. If you use a lossy compression such as Jpeg, the image quality will degrade. If you use a lossless compression such as PNG, the image quality will remain constant, but size is expected to increase. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. the thing is that the original images are jpegs.  I am only comparing the differences between the 2 images, saving it again in the same format (jpeg) and then reconstructing the current frame (as a jpeg) and over-imposing the pixel changes. At no time am I doing the loading, comparison, and saving in anything other than a jpeg.  It was an observation that when saving the changes in  the memory stream in PNG format the quality  is OK. All I can think of now is that this 3rd party tool that does the comparison is actually loading the image in a png to do it..

Comment: It doesn't matter than the initial images are Jpegs too. If you load a jpeg in photoshop and save it back to a jpeg the result will be of lower quality than the original.  Every iteration of compression will reduce the quality further, same as if you made a xerox of a xerox of a xerox.

Comment: Hi again. I see. What a total pain :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set [JPEG compression level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb882583%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when encoding your file to value that is the best empirical tradeoff between quality and size.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I tried it and whilst the quality improved it still was too poor to use unfortunately.